# How can I filter my table so that it shows the newest data possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have the following php/mysql database table called 'booking':

```
hotelNo | guestNo | dateFrom | dateTo | roomNo
   1         1     2022-03-10 2022-03-17  1   
   1         2     2019-07-01 2019-07-08  1
   4         3     2022-03-01 2022-03-09  6
   4         5     2022-07-15 2022-07-25  7
   5         6     2022-03-20 2022-03-29  10
   5         7     1987-03-10 1987-03-21  12
```

My task is to select all rooms which last had a booking that ended over two years ago.
This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT roomNo, dateTo FROM booking
WHERE Year(CURRENT_DATE)-2 > year(dateTo);
```

And the result is:

```
roomNo | dateTo
  1    2019-07-08
  12   1987-03-21
```

However, this is not correct. room 1 gets booked at 2022-03-10, therefore it shouldn't appear on the result. What should I implement in my query so that it filters out the older bookings first and then checks if the newest booking for that room ended over 2 years ago?

So far I tried using DISTINCT and ORDER BY clauses in my query but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by roomNo` and put your condition in the `having` clause:

```
select roomNo, max(dateTo) as dateTo
from booking
group by roomNo
having Year(CURRENT_DATE) - 2 > year(max(dateTo));
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=963847d0b0575e758dc22e3de323ae7e)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of rooms, I suggest using aggregation:

```sql
SELECT roomNo
FROM booking
GROUP BY roomNo
HAVING SUM(YEAR(dateTo) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 2) = 0;
```

If you want all columns, then use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT b1.*
FROM booking b1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM booking b2
    WHERE b2.roomNo = b1.roomNo AND
          YEAR(b2.dateTo) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the below

```
SELECT roomNo, dateto FROM booking where dateto =(SELECT MAX(dateto) FROM booking)
```

you can then order by roomNo or dateto.